# Why is my approach to subset sum incorrect?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am new to dynamic programming and came up with my (apparently incorrect) approach to the subset-sum-problem. I would like to know why my approach is incorrect. In particular I am curious if the underlying idea is valid at all, or if I should just stick with the normal approach to subset sum [see yt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6FhG--P7z0).

**Problem:** Given an array of numbers, find 2 subsets in the array that both have the same sum. This problem is slightly altered compared to the normal subset-sum-problem.

**Example:** `[1,5,5,9]` can be partitioned into `[1,9]` and `[5,5]`.

**Idea:**

```
   1  5  5  9
   0  5  5  9
1  1  6  6  10
5  6  5  6  10
5  6  10 10 10
9  6  10 10 10
```

Instead of keeping track of which elements I take and which not (as usual), I would like to keep track of the sum. The idea is to find the sum of the previous elements at `mem[i-1][j]` (one above the current position). If that value + the current value is smaller or equal to half of the total sum (20 in this case), we add the current value to the sum. Else, we just take the previous value and ignore the current value.

Elements that are on a diagonal in the table, will be just itself. I do this because  I would otherwise add the same element twice.

In the example, the algorithm will terminate, when it sees the first 10.

**Implementation:**

[Play with the code](https://godbolt.org/z/KKFtDi)

```
bool has_solution(std::vector<int> &v) {
    const long long sum = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    long long mem[v.size() + 1][v.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j) {
        mem[0][j] = v.at(j);
    }
    mem[0][0] = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j) {
            if (i - 1 == j) {
                mem[i][j] = v.at(i - 1);
            } else {
                const long long new_sum = mem[i - 1][j] + v.at(i - 1) ;
                if (new_sum <= sum - new_sum) {
                    mem[i][j] = new_sum;
                } else {
                    mem[i][j] = mem[i - 1][j];
                }
            }
            if (mem[i][j] * 2 == sum) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The algorithm gives the incorrect solution for the input 
`[987, 856, 743, 491, 227, 365, 859, 936, 432, 551, 437, 228, 275, 407, 474]`. It should return true, but it returns false, according to [site](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/subset-sum-problem/0).

Comment: C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays (some compilers allow them as an extension). The code `long long mem[v.size() + 1][v.size()];` will also blow up the stack if you pass a suitably large vector. I tried a 1100 element vector on godbolt and it faulted.

Comment: Good point. I think in a better version, I would use a vector. That would be much cleaner. Still, the example in godbold seems to be incorrect. So the question is: does this idea of keeping track of the sum work at all?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the issue of non-standard variable-length arrays (see comment by [Blastfurnace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445976/blastfurnace)), your concept can't work.

The flaw is that your code does not consider the possibility that two, or more, small values have to be skipped, in order to find a solution. (Note also that the code and the table you showed don't match. The code never executes the row `1  1  6  6  10`).

For example, consider the sequence:

```
{4, 1, 6, 3, 4}
```

The only valid partition is `{4, 1, 4}` and `{6, 3}`. This partition requires to skip two small entries for both partitions, which is not supported.

The run looks like:

```
  | 4   1   6    3   4
--+-------------------
4 |(0)  1   6    3   4
1 | 1  (1)  7    4   5
6 | 7   7  (7)   4   5 
3 | 7   7   7   (7)  8
4 | 7   7   7    7  (8)
```

Each column has its issue.

1. (With 4) skips the first 4, so it gives up the `{4, 1, 4}` subset. So it should skip `1`, but since it adds it this column won't work.
2. (With 1) adds `1` so it can be extended only to `{4, 1, 4}`. So it should skip `6`, but it ends adding that...
3. (With 6) adds `6` so it can be extended only to `{4, 1, 4}`, then it adds `1`, which is OK. But then it adds `3` since it is small enough (sum 4+1+3 == 8). But `3` it should have skipped it.
4. (With 3) adds `3+1+4` < 9, which is accepted by the code, but does not lead to a valid set.
5. (With 4) adds `4+1+3` <9, same as above.

If you want to use dynamic programming, you must follow the [link you posted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6FhG--P7z0). For that you need a `vector<bool>` with `sum(v) / 2 + 1` elements, initialize it with `true` on the first element, and `false` on all the rest. You can do this using only one `vector`, since you are only interested to find out **if** there is any solution, not to return it.

Your complexity would be O(sum(v) * v.size()), which may be too much if the values are big.

If the values are big, you can use `std::unordered_set<int>` instead, to code the same thing as the above `vector<bool>`, but sparsely. Complexity is more difficult to reason-about. Worst case scenario is when every subset has a different sum (for example {1, 2, 4, 8,..., 2<sup>N-2</sup>}, K >>> 2<sup>N-1</sup>}). This will make the cost O(2<sup>N</sup>) where N = v.size(). This is better than the first algorithm, which costs O(K), which is much worse than O(2<sup>N</sup>) in this case.